# Android.Database.StaleDataException: 'Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed' in Xamarin.Forms CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Created a sample with CollectionView, as an ItemsSource, accessed the device contact data through GetAllAsync() method , Facing this exception

> Android.Database.StaleDataException: 'Attempted to access a cursor
> after it has been closed'

Please refer the below code snippets for better understanding

[image]

[image]

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know that ItemsSource, of type IEnumerable, specifies the collection of items to be displayed, and has a default value of null.

Second, if you want to bind the DisplayName to the Label you need to create a `List` or `ObservableCollection`. Then binding them to the `CollectionView.Itemsource`.
you can refer to [Populate a CollectionView with data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0#define-item-appearance)

Third, about getting the Contacts you can check this [Get all contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/contacts?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#get-all-contacts)